# Add a suffix to the end of every number in a string

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation, fortran

I have some polynomial e.g. $2x^2 + 3x + 4$

In Mathematica I can define this, and convert it to a string simply enough

```
expression = 2*x^2 + 3*x + 4
expr_string = ToString[FortranForm[expression]]
```

Now, I want to append to the end of every number in the string the suffix `_dp` e.g. `2` $\rightarrow$ `2.0_dp`. I can do this simply with a `Do` loop as,

```
Do[expr_string = StringReplace[expr_string, ToString[m] -> ToString[m]<>".0_dp",{m,0,9}]
```

This works fine for single digit numbers, like in the example polynomial. But if I have numbers greater than 10, then this method fails e.g. `16` $\rightarrow$ `1.0_dp6.0_dp` since the 1 and the 6 have both been replaced.

How can I modify this method to account for double (and upwards) digit numbers such that e.g. `16` $\rightarrow$ `16.0_dp`?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you use a regular expression as the search string? in a normal regular expression one would have something like `s/[0-9]+/*.0_dp/`

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but I think you were too hasty doing that. While *accepting* is one of the [things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4), we recommend that users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. That allows people in all timezones to answer your question and an opportunity for other users to point alternatives, caveats or limitations of the available answers, in this carse Carl Woll has spotted problems with my answer.

Comment: @rhermans Ok noted. Your solution did work perfectly for my purposes though, so thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

Use the [`NumberString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberString.html) pattern.

This example works for integers only

```
StringReplace[
 ToString[FortranForm[ 1+10 x+123 x^2 ]]
,n:NumberString :> StringJoin[n,".0_dp"]
]
(* 1.0_dp + 10.0_dp*x + 123.0_dp*x**2.0_dp *)
```

Can be improved after Carl Woll's comment and snippet by J. M. this works for non-integers

```
StringReplace[
 ToString[
  1.1 + 10 x + 123.4 x^2
  , FortranForm
  ]
 , n : NumberString :> StringJoin[
   n
   , If[
    StringFreeQ[n, "."]
    , ".0_dp"
    , "0_dp"
    ]
   ]
]
(* 1.10_dp + 10.0_dp*x + 123.40_dp*x**2.0_dp *)
```

### Note

```
expr_string = ToString[FortranForm[expression]]
```

Is not a valid expression for what you want. The symbol `_` means [`Blank`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) in *Mathematica*. So `expr_string` is actually interpreted as

```
Pattern[expr, Blank[string]]
```

Comment: This won't work for something like `1.1 + 10 x + 123 x^2`. or `2+x2`.

Comment: Still doesn't work for `2+x2`. Basically, I think the StringReplace approach throws away information that is present in the Mathematica expression (what is an integer, what is a symbol and what is a real), and the approach giving Integer a FortranForm format doesn't.

Comment: I did in my answer to the linked question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97777/discussion-between-carl-woll-and-rhermans).

Comment: @user49047 I suggest you post an answer with you insights or comment on the chat.

Answer (score 0):

One can use the Replace function and use a simple pattern

```
Replace[expression, a : _?NumericQ :> ToString[N[a]] <> "0_dp", Infinity]
```

Or with FortranForm

```
Replace[FortranForm@N[expression], 
 a : _?NumericQ :> ToString[a] <> "0_dp", Infinity]
```